# How to do a Wisdom check without a target number?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

I'm playing D&D 5e and using a solo book 'To Hell and Back'. In B1 (p. 12) it seems to call for a Wisdom check without a target number. Is the correct method to give the 'Wisdom Check' a comparison number from a difficulty perspective?

My skills a getting better every day, but this has me stumped a bit.

Comment: Just as a comment on the title of the question: there are also “opposed” checks, where the target is not a predefined number but the outcome of another, opposed skill roll. An example would be Charisma (Deception) vs Wisdom (Insight) - both sides roll, add their bonuses, and the higher result wins.

Answer (score 10):

My version of the pdf, on page 12, section B1 says:

> Make a DC12 wisdom saving throw. If the saving throw fails, make a note that you have the trait 'fear of bony things'.

Generally every save or check should have an associated difficulty, as I think you have realised. Sometimes instead of a number you may see a difficulty, such as easy, medium or hard. There is a table in the players handbook that says what those correspond to, but your module uses a different (better in my opinion) definition given on page 1.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I'll make the check 'easy' then. I've failed the test anyway, as I got a bad roll. Humph.

Comment: I get you now! It's got a DC of 10, thanks for your time.

Comment: @DaveDiamond the text in my version (and my answer) is DC12. It is a little after the flavour text, so maybe in this module always read the entire section (all of B1) and the information should be within somewhere. At first glance all the checks and saves I could see had a corresponding DC in bold text nearby.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hope you live up to your name! This is not life and death, it's more important.

Comment: @DaveDiamond: Also note that a saving throw is not the same as a skill check. They're two different kinds of rolls, albeit both using a d20.